# The right way to achieve SSR with React.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I wanted to achieve SSR in my React app. According the research I did, the benefits of achieving SSR with React app are firstly, SEO and faster painting making a page render faster(but not interactive until JS is parsed and run). Then, I came across something called Next.js but it says that it can potentially make code a bit verbose and thus I decided to do the following. TO achieve SEO, I found prerender.io and to achieve performance I think about code splitting(progressive rendering). Guys, are prerender.io + progressive rendering appropriate combination instead of Next.js?